# How to add one2many field of custom model to the tree view in Openerp?

Tags: odoo

I want to add a selection field to the form view and show the selection in tree view.

I first tried adding a custom selection field to the model but since I have many values to add to the selection field I bumped to the `char(128)` limit of the selection field of `ir.model` model.

Second I created a new custom model named x_newmodel with 3 fiedls with names `x_name`,  `x_code`,  `x_description` 
added a `one2many` field `x_newfield` connecting to the `x_newmodel` solved the problem with the form view.
However when I try to add the new field `x_newfield` to the tree view I cannot get to show the data on the view.

**My question is how can I add the field one2many relationship of the custom field to the tree view?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not supported.

What you could do is add a function field on your model which would compute

```
','.join(elem.name for elem in obj.x_newfield)
```

and use this in your tree display.

If you need to add a filter, you can implement the search function for your function field.

Comment: Thanks, maybe creating a new module with only my custom model as a base model can be easier.